# require anonymous data structure

Tags: perl

Is there someway to require an anonymous data structure in perl?

```
#test.pl
(
  "example_data" => 1
)

#main.pl
require "test.pl";
%some_data = (%some_data, $);
```

Does require implicitly return the data structure if 1 is not at the end like subs do?

Here is a more specific example of what I am doing. Keep in mind the data objects will be much larger than the one provided.

```
#main.pl
use Schedular(
  \%CONFIG,
  do "default.pl"
);

#spawn new process for each schedule
Schedular::run_schedulue("some_schedule"); 
Schedular::run_schedulue("some_other_schedule");

#Schedular.pm

package Schedular;

our %schedules = undef;
our %config = undef;
sub import{
   %config= shift @_;
   %schedules = shift @_;
}

sub run_schedule{
  #Run each event in schedule
}

sub do_something{
   print("Hello World");
}

#default.pl
(
  "some_schedule"=>[
       sub {
            #Event
            Schedular::do_something();
       },
       sub {
           #Event 2
       }
   ],
   "some_other_schedule"=>[
       sub {
          #Event 3
        },
   ]
)
1;
```

The main purpose is I want to be able to generate new perl scripts easily using data objects as templates/recipes of the scripts logic and leave the implementation to the Schedular module. This also easily allow me to push new events onto a schedule and add new schedules on the fly.

Comment: `$some_data = do "test.pl"; #--> {foo =>1}`

Comment: thanks, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Use `do` (not `require`) for `.pl` files. (`require` is for modules.) And yes, make sure to return a true value to detect problems loading.

Comment: @TheAschr: *"thanks, exactly what i was looking for"* No. It probably isn't. But without any information on the context and what `test.pl`, `main.pl` and `%some_data` might *really* be we can't help you any better. `do` is a relic from Perl 4 days and you probably want a module. But who can tell?

Comment: I don't want to use a module because I want only a single data structure to be in the file and I want it to have access to the calling files data. Basically main.pl takes a user submitted test.pl and operates on it.

Comment: if you are processing a user input you might want to have the user provide the input in a CSV (or JSON, XML or YAML if the data is complex), as they're a bit more universal than Perl data structures.

Comment: @Сухой27 `do`, like `require`, searches `@INC` for the given path name.  better to qualify it (especially in preparation for newer versions of perl that exclude `.` from @INC)

Comment: My structure is actually to complex for those as it has perl subroutines inside of it.

Comment: @TheAschr, like @Borodin already said, it is probably not what you want - but who can tell. Please use a data-structure file format like YAML. Besides that 'any' code in that `test.pl` would be executed as part of the perl script ... that can really be anything!

Comment: @TheAschr: *"I don't want to use a module because I want only a single data structure to be in the file and I want it to have access to the calling files data"* Then your design is wrong. You need to define a *module* that contains a *subroutine* to which you can pass the local data. The subroutine can build and return the data structure that you require. But again, who can tell? You have given us only the very tiniest bits of information and it's really anyone's guess. Just don't use `do` or `require` unless you have an *extraordinary* reason to do so. Not understanding `use` doesn't count.

Comment: @vanHoesel: I'm not sure that serialising the data would help, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'm nervous about sharing specific code because it is a work project and I am not sure what the licensing is or even if there is any. I have a module that that takes the data object as a parameter. I just wanted a way to have a bunch of object files that can be easily readable (by other programmers) and only contain logic with no implementation. I would like to use JSON or such but the objects describe instructions rather than definitions and it seems like that would be cumbersome.

Comment: Perhaps someone can post a simple example of this sub-providing module as an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "_object files_"?  Files that contain code (is that "_logic_"?) that can make its way to main? And is "_data object_" data to operate on in some other file?

Comment: I also don't get "_object with no implementation_" that would "_describe instructions_".  A riddle to me :)

Comment: I have updated my question try to clear things up. It probably has mistakes but it illustrates what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is so difficult to clarify the objective.

Here is an attempt at something concrete: Return a [code reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) from a module's sub. What that code returns when run is driven by data from the caller (and other modules), to any complexity.

The module `CodeGen.pm`

```
package CodeGen;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(pp);

use FuncStubs qw(f_stub);

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(get_coderef);

sub get_coderef {
    my @pars = @_; 
    # Any variables declared here and used in sub 
    # will still exist in the caller ("closure")
    my $rc = sub {
        my @rc_pars = @_; 
        my $data = pp \@rc_pars;  # for demo
        my $hashref = { 
            key => $data, func => \&f_stub 
        }; 
        return $hashref;
    };  
    return $rc;
}

1;
```

and utility `FuncStubs.pm` with user-supplied code

```
package FuncStubs;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(f_stub);

sub f_stub { print "In ", __PACKAGE__, ", got: @_\n" }

1;
```

The caller, your `main.pl`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use CodeGen qw(get_coderef);
    
my $data = { from_main => 'some_data' };
        
my $rc = get_coderef($data);
        
my $ret = $rc->($data);
dd $ret;

$ret->{func}->("From_" . __PACKAGE__) ;
```

This prints

```
{ func => sub { ... }, key => "[{ from_main => \"some_data\" }]" }
In FuncStubs, got: From_main
```

The `get_coderef` uses `$data` to build the code reference, which it returns. That `$rc` can then be run at will, with its own arguments. As needs of the code change you can run `get_coderef` again, with new data, and thus build a new `$rc`, etc.

The `FuncStubs` is also used to build `$rc`, as my guess for your need for user-supplied code.

I would think that you can use this to build a system that functions like what you're describing (but what I don't fully understand). Please clarify how it relates, or not, to what you are talking about.

Comment: I have updated my question try to clear things up. It probably has mistakes but it illustrates what I am trying to do.

Comment: @TheAschr  Thank you.  I still don't see the point, in particular with the stated absence of "_implementation_" and which modules are supposed to provide what.  An example. In my answer, the `GiveCode`  can load yet other modules, say with "stubs" for functions; then `$rc` can use those stubs as it pleases. So when `$rc` is returned the `main` will acquire that functionality.  Is that along the lines of what you have in mind?

Comment: From what I can tell your code more or less functions similar to mine. The main difference I can see is that your approach uses modules to export the data whereas mine just uses do. Since I'm treating the object file strictly as an object that is an extension of the main program, won't it cause issues having to import it multiple times using "use"? Since "use" is interpreted at compile time won't it also lose it's template like characteristics? For example it will likely be modified during run-time. Also I may need to build multiple copies by importing it multiple times. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TheAschr I am not sure what are concerns here.  In principle, better use modules than `do`.  Why would multiple imports be a problem? That's precisely what `use` provides (by using `require`), that it is safe to do so.  If you need to clone them, once you have a coderef (`$rc`) you can pass it and copy it all you want; it's just a scalar. Yes, `use` goes at compile time but I don't see how (and what) code is supposed to be modified at runtime. Note that `$rc` is both created and take its input at runtime. Your question should really have more specifics; it's hard to be guessing like this.

Comment: @TheAschr Added another module whose subs are passed via `$rc`.

Comment: @TheAschr  How did this go in the end? Should I add/clarify things ...?

Answer (score 0):

> Does require implicitly return the data structure if 1 is not at the end like subs do?

I'm not sure if this is documented, but the answer is: Sort of, but no.

The first time you `require` a file, it will return the value of the last expression evaluated, like a subroutine (or really, like `do`). But any subsequent `require` of the same file will simply return `1`.

This means using `require` to get a meaningful value from the file isn't a reliable method. If anyone else (e.g. a module loaded by another module loaded by you) has loaded the file first, you'll only see `1`.